# Building Perl Soap Services that are Consumed by .NET

Tags: .net, perl, soap, wsdl, service-reference

I have a Linux server with Perl libraries that I need to expose to a .NET application.  Naturally I thought I would build out a platform independent solution, like SOAP, to bridge the gap.  I'm finding this is not as easy as I was expecting.

As a mini proof of concept, I am trying to build out a hello world service in Perl.  I've generated my code based off of this tutorial:

http://guide.soaplite.com/#quick%20start%20guide%20with%20soap%20and%20soap::lite

And peppered in some Pod::SOAP commenting that I found here:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=632923

And ended up with this service:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI->dispatch_to('Demo')-> handle;

package Demo;

=begin WSDL
_RETURN $string
=end WSDL
=cut

sub hi {
    return "hello, world";
}
```

I generated a WSDL with this script:

```
#!#!/usr/bin/perl
use Pod::WSDL;

my $pod = new Pod::WSDL(source => '/var/www/html/perl/test.pl', location => 'http://localhost/perl/test.pl', pretty => 1, withDocumentation =>1);

print $pod->WSDL;
```

Low and behold, when I hit this script, I get a WSDL.  I load it in to .NET 4.0 as a ServiceReference and think life is grand.  But it's not.

When I try to envoke the reference like this:

```
var myWS = new ServiceReference1.DemoHandlerClient(new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(url));
string result = myWS.hi();
```

I end up getting this error out of the soap request:

> SOAPAction shall match 'uri#method' if present (got
>   'http://localhost/Demo/DemoHandler/hiRequest', expected
>   'http://localhost/Demo#hi'

Clearly I see that .NET is not submitting the expected SOAPAction.  What can I do to fix this?  I suspect that if I were to use the perl SOAP::Lite library for the client that this would work fine.

**Edit**: Perhaps weirder yet--If I use Fiddler to capture the XML that .NET is sending over, and then manually send the same XML over using SoapUI I end up getting a valid response.

Comment: while the XML content is identical but not the requests, the most probable cause is the SOAPAction HTTP header, Try to *play* with it in Fiddler and soapUI. It also could help if you'll post your WSDL file (at least a link).

Comment: Yea I figured out that the SOAPAction was not doing as expected, and fiddled with that.  Next up was the error "Application failed during request deserialization: no element found at line 1, column 0, byte -1 at /usr/lib/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `SOAP::Lite` in 2006 to build a web service and it was such a bad experience that I've avoided ever since like the devil avoids holy water. If you are serious indeed on going the SOAP road, then I would very much suggest getting acquainted with [`XML::Compile`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aCompile) suite of modules for XML Schema, SOAP and WSDL. I found the module much nicer to work with and there is a mailing list and the author is very responsive.

Take a look at [`XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aSOAP%3a%3aDaemon) to learn how to build a server.

Comment: I will look into that and get back to you.  Do you have any good examples handy?

Comment: Ultimately I Think you are right, though I think XML::Compile is more of a beast than I'm looking for as well.  I am going to build out some simple rest based cgi scripts that return XML.  It would have been nice to have some WSDLs to work with however.  I used this as a reference for building out a simple REST script: http://www.lifecycle-ps.com/blog/?p=93